# Are there any performance downsides to attaching numerous methods to every DOM element?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

Seeing as you are able to attach methods to DOM elements, like so:

```
<div id="fizz"></div>
```

```
document.getElementById('fizz').method1 = foo => doSomething(foo);
```

```
document.getElementById('fizz').method1(prop);
```

Would there be any noticeable downsides to attaching, say, the same 20 functions to every DOM element on the page?

I know I could probably do:

```
Element.prototype.foo = foo => doSomething(foo);
```

But for my usecase I need to make the target DOM elements controllable, but must assume all DOM elements may be targeted.

Apologies if this question is too broad for Stackoverflow - hopefully it's ok.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to add your own properties to DOM elements or prototypes, because it might conflict with a property that gets added to the standard in the future.

Comment: @Barmar that's a very good point, I'm not sure there's any way I could justify doing this now, which is a shame because it would be so convenient for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation for why you don't put it on the prototype. If you use a traditional function instead of an arrow function, `this` will be set to the targeted element.

Comment: @Barmar I can't put it on the prototype because I need to choose which DOM elements I want to add the function to, I don't necessarily want to add them to all DOM elements, only certain ones.

Comment: Well, if you're going to do it, I don't see why you couldn't do it at the element level. You'll use a bit more memory having a separate closure for each element, but that's the price you pay for being specific.

Comment: You could have a prototype method and add a `data-xxx` attribute to the elements that need to be controlled. The method can use `this.dataset.xxx` to check it.

Comment: Well, for my usecase, elsewhere inside my framework, at some point I have access to every DOM element I am interested in already, at which point I can then attach the methods. Would it still be better to do it at the Element level?